# Issue when boxing 4 uchar into an int (RenderScript)

Tags: android, c, renderscript

In my RenderScript program, I want to return a 32bit integer representing color (to be directly a color in the Java framework), so I do this that way:

RS code:

```
static const uchar k = 51;
static const uchar d = 5;
static int32_t histo[52][52][52];
....

int __attribute__((kernel)) getResult() {
    int maximum = 0;
    uchar3 vect = {0, 0, 0};
    ....
    loops through histogram and puts max's coordinates into vect
    ...
    // Convert coords back to [0, 255] space
    vect.r = (uchar) (vect.s0*d + d/2);
    vect.g = (uchar) (vect.s1*d + d/2);
    vect.b = (uchar) (vect.s2*d + d/2);

    return (0xff) << 24 | (vect.r & 0xff) << 16 | (vect.g & 0xff) << 8 | (vect.b & 0xff);
}
```

Java code:

```
 Allocation bmpAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);

 // Allocation where to store the result color (for output purposes)
 Allocation colorAlloc = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.I32(rs), 1);

 ScriptC_findcolor scriptC = new ScriptC_findcolor(rs);
 scriptC.forEach_channelHist(bmpAlloc);
 scriptC.forEach_getResult(colorAlloc);

 int[] a = new int[1];
 colorAlloc.copyTo(a);
 int color = a[0];
```

It works perfectly when using a x86 emulator, but for some reason with a real device the value received in Java side is completely random.

As you can see, the alpha channel is hardcoded to 255 (0xff) in the .rs script, but on the Java side value is not 255 at all (102, 164 ...).

Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: You didn't show how you are reading the value. My guess is that as `int color` a packed 32 bit integer value, you have to be aware of big-endian/little-endian differences between ARM and Intel.

Comment: In fact I did, look at the last 3 lines ofvthe java code. I got it thanks to an answer on androidev reddit, I'll post an update, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it thanks to an answer (thank you @Izacus) on androidev reddit. 
First:

- `vect.r & 0xff` and other clipping operations in the return statement won't do a thing, because vect.r is uchar and it'll wrap around [0, 255] range by itself. So to avoid confusion I changed that line to:

  ```
  return 0xff << 24 | vect.r << 16 | vect.g << 8 | vect.b;
  ```
- Using `int` type is dangerous when targeting multiple platform, use `int32_t` instead.

So, the problem was in fact into the bitwise operation. `vect.r`, `vect.g` and `vect.b` are **unsigned** chars and it seems to cause an overflow or a shift or something when summing them with `|` operator to create a **signed** 32bit integer.

To fix it, I changed `uchar3 vect;` to `int3 vect;`